# Trying to force some kind of IEnumerable.Each-method

Tags: c#, razor, ienumerable

I have the following snipped inside a Razor-file:

```
<td>@item.Mottakere.All(q => {
    @q.Epost <br />
})</td>
```

Where `@item` is a object from a `foreach ... Model.ToList()` and `@item.Mottaker` is a `List` inside this object.

I know this doesn't work, mostly because All expects a bool, and also because I can't inline razor in a lambda this way... But is there any way I could force this kind of functionality? Or should I just do a normal nested `foreach` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I invite you to checkout [Templated Razor Delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx).

Comment: That was a daunting name, but I'll check it out ;)

Answer (score 1):

`All` doesn't expect bool, but it returns `true` when the given lambda is `true` for every item in the list - for example Are all apples in the list red?

In your case, when you want to output the elements in Mottakere, you'll have to use another `foreach` or use some helper method. For example see [this](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-list-helper-extension-method/).